# How to redraw jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

```js
//start job schedule 

function nth(d)  { if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';  switch (d % 10) { case 1:  return "st"; case 2:  return "nd"; case 3:  return "rd"; default: return "th"; } }
function dateToYMD(date) { var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; var d = date.getDate(); var m = strArray[date.getMonth()]; var y = date.getFullYear(); return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y; }
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) { var date = new Date(this.valueOf()); date.setDate(date.getDate() + days); return date; }
function pad(str) { return (" "+str).slice(-2) }
//var cnt = 0;
var dataSet = [];

function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays,cnt) {
  var numWorkDays = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  var premises = "Innovation Building in DMC";
  var Time = "Day";
  var typeoftreatment = "Residual-spray / Dust / bait & Traps"
  while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
      numWorkDays = 0;
      cnt++;
      let date = dateToYMD(currentDate);
      let pos = holidays.indexOf(date);
      if (pos != -1) {
        console.log("replace",date,"with",instead[pos])
        date = instead[pos];
      }  
      let treatment = pad(cnt) + nth(cnt) + (cnt == 1 ? " Basic" : " Control") + " Treatment"
      dataSet.push([premises, typeoftreatment, treatment, date, Time])
    }
  }
}

 var holidays = [];//assign holidays days here
 var instead = [];
 holidays.forEach((hol,i) => {
   let d = new Date(hol);
   let date = d.getDate() + 1
   d.setDate(date); // next day (could be Weekend);
   while (d.getDay() === 5) {
  date++;
  d.setDate(date); // is any day not friday ok?
   }
   instead.push(dateToYMD(d))
   holidays[i] = dateToYMD(new Date(hol))
 })

$('.jobshepest').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {    
    $('.examplejobshecdule').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
   data: dataSet,
   columns: [
   { title: "Premises" },
   { title: "Type of treatment" },
   { title: "Frequency" },
   { title: "Date" },
   {title: "Time"}],
   order: [[2, "asc"]],
   columnDefs: [
            { width: "23%", targets: 3 }
        ]
    });
   
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/demo/sam.css');?>" media="all"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
 
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
    <!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/demo/sam.js');?>"></script>
    

<div class="modal fade jobshepest" id="viewactipestmodal" role="document">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: initial !important">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalschedulepest">schedule report pest</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
      
                   <!-- <form id="newModalFormviewschedpest" name="viewschedulepest" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                      <fieldset disabled="disabled">
                       <div class="period" style="float:left; padding: 5px; text-align:right; font-family: monospace;"  id="first">Date<hr/> 
      </div>
    <div class="period" style="float:left; padding: 5px; text-align:right; font-family: monospace;" id="second">Frequency<hr/></div>
                      </fieldset>
                    </form>-->
       <table id="examplejobshecdule" class="table table-striped table-bordered examplejobshecdule" style="width:100%">
                      
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date('2019-01-01'), new Date('2020-01-01'),26,0);"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">1st button</button>
            
<button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date('2019-01-01'), new Date('2019-12-31'),15,0);"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">2nd button</button>
            
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

when i click the first button, popup modal will open and results will show (calling through calling a function) - **12 entries** is there
after closing the modal and try to click the 2nd button,

when second button clicks, another dates are passing in the argument- 
**20 entries** is there. But the problem is 12+20=32 entries are showing up..ITs wrong..How to fix it??I need to show 12 entries for the 1st button clicks and 20 entries for the second button clicks everytime

i tried redraw, fndestry and all ..its not working.

can anyone plz help me to do this?

Comment: Please describe the result you get with your current code.

Comment: Okay. Can you provide the HTML as well?

Comment: You are saying both "*When reopen again the modal i want to **remove** previous data and will show new datas*" and "*Now the problem is **adding** previous datas with the new datas*". Do you want to **remove** or **add** the new data?

Comment: Please put ALL your code as a snippet so I can reproduce the problem. I tried doing it myself but it seems there is code missing from you question.

Comment: @RawlandHustle http://jsfiddle.net/jm91go3s/ here is the datatable showing in inside modal

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no modal in your code.

Comment: The different bits of code you have supplied results in an empty table since `dataSet` is an empty array. I can help you if you provide me with a working version of your code in a code snippet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1711950.

Comment: @RawlandHustle added snippet also plz check it...addetwo different button with same className and different Datespassing throgh function - every button click am calling a fucntion with different dates..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jm91go3s/    plz check this also this  is the results am showing in modal popup

Comment: @RawlandHustle can u plz answer it?

Comment: I will take a look now.

Comment: @RawlandHustle ok sir i will wait for ur reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `printNextPeriod` pushed new data to `dataSet` everytime you clicked the button. I have added `dataSet = [];` inside `printNextPeriod` to reset the data.

```js
//start job schedule 

function nth(d)  { if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';  switch (d % 10) { case 1:  return "st"; case 2:  return "nd"; case 3:  return "rd"; default: return "th"; } }
function dateToYMD(date) { var strArray=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']; var d = date.getDate(); var m = strArray[date.getMonth()]; var y = date.getFullYear(); return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + m + '-' + y; }
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) { var date = new Date(this.valueOf()); date.setDate(date.getDate() + days); return date; }
function pad(str) { return (" "+str).slice(-2) }
//var cnt = 0;
var dataSet = [];

function printNextPeriod(startDate, endDate, periodInDays,cnt) {
  dataSet = [];
  var numWorkDays = 0;
  var currentDate = new Date(startDate);
  var premises = "Innovation Building in DMC";
  var Time = "Day";
  var typeoftreatment = "Residual-spray / Dust / bait & Traps"
  while (numWorkDays < periodInDays && currentDate <= endDate) {
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
    // Skips friday
    if (currentDate.getDay() !== 5) {
      numWorkDays++;
    }
    if (numWorkDays == periodInDays) {
      numWorkDays = 0;
      cnt++;
      let date = dateToYMD(currentDate);
      let pos = holidays.indexOf(date);
      if (pos != -1) {
        console.log("replace",date,"with",instead[pos])
        date = instead[pos];
      }  
      let treatment = pad(cnt) + nth(cnt) + (cnt == 1 ? " Basic" : " Control") + " Treatment"
      dataSet.push([premises, typeoftreatment, treatment, date, Time])
    }
  }
}

 var holidays = [];//assign holidays days here
 var instead = [];
 holidays.forEach((hol,i) => {
   let d = new Date(hol);
   let date = d.getDate() + 1
   d.setDate(date); // next day (could be Weekend);
   while (d.getDay() === 5) {
  date++;
  d.setDate(date); // is any day not friday ok?
   }
   instead.push(dateToYMD(d))
   holidays[i] = dateToYMD(new Date(hol))
 })

$('.jobshepest').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {    
    $('.examplejobshecdule').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
   data: dataSet,
   columns: [
   { title: "Premises" },
   { title: "Type of treatment" },
   { title: "Frequency" },
   { title: "Date" },
   {title: "Time"}],
   order: [[2, "asc"]],
   columnDefs: [
            { width: "23%", targets: 3 }
        ]
    });
   
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/demo/sam.css');?>" media="all"/>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
 
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 
    <!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/demo/sam.js');?>"></script>
    

<div class="modal fade jobshepest" id="viewactipestmodal" role="document">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: initial !important">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalschedulepest">schedule report pest</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
      
                   <!-- <form id="newModalFormviewschedpest" name="viewschedulepest" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                      <fieldset disabled="disabled">
                       <div class="period" style="float:left; padding: 5px; text-align:right; font-family: monospace;"  id="first">Date<hr/> 
      </div>
    <div class="period" style="float:left; padding: 5px; text-align:right; font-family: monospace;" id="second">Frequency<hr/></div>
                      </fieldset>
                    </form>-->
       <table id="examplejobshecdule" class="table table-striped table-bordered examplejobshecdule" style="width:100%">
                      
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date('2019-01-01'), new Date('2020-01-01'),26,0);"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">1st button</button>
            
<button onclick="printNextPeriod(new Date('2019-01-01'), new Date('2019-12-31'),15,0);"  class="btn btn-success btn-sm actpest" data-target="#viewactipestmodal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal">2nd button</button>
            
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @numukisdf No problem! :)

Comment: helo sir do u know how to pass these results (calling function printNextPeriod) to database through AJAX

Comment: I need to insert date and frequency